# Many To Many relation laravel with the name "ImageCode"

Tags: many-to-many, laravel, laravel-4

I am wondering how I should be able to make a many to many relation with a class/table containing two words.

I made a database table with migration which had the name of "image_codes". And I wanted a "user" to be able to have many "image_codes" and one "image_code" can have many "users". So my problem is how should I be able to make this relation and what should my model be called.

The name of the many to many table were 'image_code_user'

When I tried this out:

```
class ImageCode extends Eloquent {
    public $table = 'image_codes';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'image_code_user');
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent {
    public $table = 'users';

    public function image_codes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('ImageCode', 'image_code_user');
    }
}


/**
 * The result below this lines....
 **/

$user = User::find(1);
var_dump($user->image_codes) 
// Outcome is NULL
```

I tried alot of different ways but always the same outcome, it worked if i made.

```
$image_code = ImageCode::find(1);
var_dump($image_code->users) 
// All users were returned
```

Now I started to wonder if something is wrong with my table image_codes isn't it possible to use a word that contains two words talking about "ImageCode". So I tried to remake everything but then using the name "Code" instead.

The name of the many to many table were 'code_user'

```
class Code extends Eloquent {
    public $table = 'codes';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'code_user');
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent {
    public $table = 'users';

    public function image_codes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Code', 'code_user');
    }
}


/**
 * The result below this lines....
 **/

$user = User::find(1);
var_dump($user->codes) 
// All codes were returned
```

So please Stack overflow. Can someone tell me how I should make a correct ManyToMany relation with the word 'ImageCode' and 'User'

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.laravelbook.com/eloquent/#one-to-one

According to the documentation, in the User model, the second parameter of belongsToMany function is used to define the foreign key of the Image_Codes table, not the name of the intermediate/pivot/middle table which I assume you're trying to do right here.

Right now you have two model: ImageCode and User.

Laravel by default combine the name of these two model for the name of the pivot table, in this case it is imagecode_user.

You can first try to delete the second argument of you belongsToMany function and then rename your pivot table to imagecode_user.

If you insist to have your pivot table named image_code_user, rename your ImageCode model to Image_Code.

Of course the perfect solution would be to define the pivot table name as image_code_user and have the two model named ImageCode and User since it is much more elegant to write ImageCode::find(1) then to write Image_Code::find(1). Unfortunately, I don't have an answer for that.

Comment: http://doc.laravelbook.com/eloquent/#many-to-many according to this they say "If you would like to use an unconventional table name for your pivot table, you may pass it as the second argument to the belongsToMany method:" So I think you're wrong but I've not tried your answer. I will try it out on another similiar thing tonight or maybe tomorrow.